# JavaScript Telerik if replacement

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

Using teleriks drag and drop demo I'm able to reproduce the functionality, however, what I want to do is if the browser isn't HTML5 compliant I want to load a different function.  Below is the code i'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = $telerik.$;
    function pageLoad() {
        if (!Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.FileApi.isAvailable()) {
            $(".wrapper").replaceWith(
                $("<span><strong>Your browser does not support Drag and Drop. Please take a look at the info box for additional information.</strong></span>"));
        }
    }

    function added(sender, args) {
        if (Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.FileApi.isAvailable()) {

            $(".ruDropZone").html("<div align=\"center\"><img src=\"images/logo.png\" width = \"300\"></div>");
        }
    }

</script>
```

I realize that you want to replace this section with the code you want:

```
if (!Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.FileApi.isAvailable()) {
            $(".wrapper").replaceWith(
```

How do I include whats below in this in the .replaceWith(

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="RadAsyncUpload1" OnClientAdded="added" OnFileUploaded="RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded">
    </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
    <br />
    <telerik:RadProgressManager ID="Radprogressmanager1" runat="server" />

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="controlContainer">
                    <telerik:RadUpload
                        ID="RadUpload1" runat="server"
                        MaxFileInputsCount="5"
                        OverwriteExistingFiles="false" />

                    <telerik:RadProgressArea id="progressArea1" runat="server"/>

                    <asp:Button id="buttonSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="RadUploadSubmit" OnClick="buttonSubmit_Click" text="Submit" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="smallModule">
                        <div class="rc1"><div class="rc2"><div class="rc3" style="width:240px">

                            <asp:Label ID="labelNoResults" runat="server" Visible="True">No uploaded files yet</asp:Label>

                            <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterResults" runat="server" Visible="False">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <div class="title">Uploaded files in the target folder:</div>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName")%>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ContentLength").ToString() + " bytes"%>
                                    <br />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div></div></div></div>
                            </td>
                            </tr>                              
                            </table>
                            </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Never done this before, but my thoughts are merely theoretical.  Can you wrap that code inside of a div (or an ASP.NET System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel object?).  The div tag will get rendered out in HTML from the Panel web control.  Figure out what the id of that div is, and get the innerHTML of that div.  The innerHTML is what gets rendered out with the code you have.

Comment: Hmm just tried and yeah that doesn't work :)

Comment: your comment help lead me to the answer so thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help.. what confused me before is that I didn't see a tag with id="wrapper" (or class named "wrapper") in the code snippet from the question.  I'm assuming it's done using a div with an id of wrapper (in the code example you found on google or your reference material).  Hence wrapping (surrounding) the other code, and then replacing what's in that wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, by creating additional divs and hiding elements based on divs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = $telerik.$;
    function pageLoad() {
        if (!Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.FileApi.isAvailable()) {
            $(".wrapper").replaceWith(
            $("")); 
        }
    }

    function added(sender, args) {
        if (Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.FileApi.isAvailable()) {

            $(".ruDropZone").html("<div align=\"center\"><img src=\"images/logo.png\" width = \"300\"></div>");
            $(".nonHTML5").replaceWith(
            $(""));
        }
    }

</script>

<div class="wrapper">

    <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="RadAsyncUpload1" OnClientAdded="added" OnFileUploaded="RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded">
    </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
    <br />
    <telerik:RadProgressManager ID="Radprogressmanager1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class ="nonHTML5" style="position:relative;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="controlContainer">
                    <telerik:RadUpload
                        ID="RadUpload1" runat="server"
                        MaxFileInputsCount="5"
                        OverwriteExistingFiles="false" />

                    <telerik:RadProgressArea id="progressArea1" runat="server"/>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="smallModule">
                        <div class="rc1"><div class="rc2"><div class="rc3" style="width:240px">

                            <asp:Label ID="labelNoResults" runat="server" Visible="True">No uploaded files yet</asp:Label>

                            <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterResults" runat="server" Visible="False">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <div class="title">Uploaded files in the target folder:</div>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName")%>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ContentLength").ToString() + " bytes"%>
                                    <br />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div></div></div></div>
                            </td>
                            </tr>                              
                            </table>
                            </div>
                            <asp:Button id="buttonSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="RadUploadSubmit" OnClick="buttonSubmit_Click" text="Submit" />
                            </td>
                            </tr>
```